# Can we deploy the matlab generated java code on any other machine which is not having Matlab?

Tags: java, matlab, matlab-deployment

I have generated a java code from matlab and while executing the java code in Eclipse it is using mclmcrrt711.dll file in matlab compiler runtime, when i try to execute the java code in another machine which is not having matlab or matlab compiler it is giving me the **error:"java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Failed to find the library mclmcrrt711.dll, required by MATLAB Builder JA, on java.library.path"** i tried adding the mclmcrrt711.dll file to the library and by setting system path to that dll file location(as copied just the .dll file to other system which is not having matlab compiler). How can i overcome this error?? Please help me out.

Thank you in advance
Srikanth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use Java components that use MATLAB on a machine that does not have MATLAB installed on it, you will need to install the [MATLAB Compiler Runtime](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/compiler/f12-999353.html) (MCR).  I am assuming you are using [MATLAB Builder JA](http://www.mathworks.com/products/javabuilder/description1.html). You should have the MCR installer on the MATLAB install CD.  You can contact [The MathWorks](http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/index.html) and they will be able to help you get the MCR installer in the event you downloaded your copy of MATLAB.

Comment: thanx alot for your reply.... i am trying to use that java code in a mobile...so will that be possible to install the MCR on mobile??

Comment: Sadly this is not possible.  The MATLAB runtime requires the entire Java SE and much of the runtime is arch specific.  Most mobile phones use small chips like ARM that are not currently supported. You can use the latest version of MATLAB on your mobile device, but that is somewhat of a lie because all you are doing is connecting to your desktop via a remote session.  The short answer is however no, you cannot run your MATLAB JA code on a mobile device.

Comment: thanx alot for your reply, this helps me to get out of the confusion.. do u think we any other way to implement a low pass filter in java,which could as well work in a mobile...please help me out with this...

Comment: You can write just about anything you want.  A low-pass filter in Java might be kind of slow, which is why you were using MATLAB I assume. I would find out how to write a native library for the phone, find a Linear Algebra library for that architecture, write a native library to do the heavy lifting then use JNI to marshal results into your Java code... basically write your own small MATLAB engine.